# Largest domain where $\text{Log}(z-z_0)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I need to find the largest domain where $\text{Log}(z-z_0)$ with the definition that $\text{Log} z = \ln |z| +\text{Arg} \ z$ is analytic. I know that $\text{Log} \ z$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-D^* $, where $D^* = \{x+iy; x\le 0, y=0\}$

But how to apply that for $\text{Log}(z-z_0)$? Wouldn't it be just the set $S = \{z; \text{Re}(z-z_0)\le 0, \text{Im}(z-z_0)=0\}$?

Comment: There is no "the" largest domain.   There are many maximal domains i.e you cannot define log on anything bigger than those sets.  For  example $\log(z)$ can be defined  on $D'$ instead of $D^*$, where $D'=\{ x + iy, x\geq 0, x=y \}$.

Comment: See [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm) of the Riemann surface where $\log z$ is analytic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that with $\log z=\log|z|+i\arg z$ you mean the principal logarithm.

As you already pointed out, this particular branch of the complex logarithm is holomorphic on the whole so called *slit-plane*, $\Bbb C_-:=\Bbb C\setminus{\Bbb R_{\le0}}$, which is in fact the biggest domain on which the principal logarithm is holomorphic.

Considering the traslation $z\mapsto\log(z-z_0)$, this function is in fact holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus{S}$, where 
$$
S_{z_0}:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;\Re(z-z_0)\le0,\;\Im(z-z_0)=0\}
$$
which corresponds to the horizontal half line starting from $z_0$ and going leftward; cutting this set from the complex plane, your logarithm is indeed holomorphic.